# Need to display 3 images in a row on desktop, same 3 stacked vertically on mobile

Tags: responsive

So i have seen some interesting solutions for this around the web, but the rub here is that i do not have access to the master CSS and scripting is turned off, so it will have to be done with inline CSS or none at all.

The images are links to subscribe to a podcast on Spotify, Google, and Apple podcasts. This is of course very easy on the desktop version. i have them sized to 30% each and it works fine.

When looking on the mobile view, it ALMOST does the right thing but instead of:

SPOTIFY
GOOGLE
APPLE

what i get is:

SPOTIFY GOOGLE

APPLE

At least Apple is centered under the other two. It is responding to the switch to mobile, but what i would like is a stack of 3 big buttons that are easy to tap on small phones.

i know what i would do if i could use CSS calls, but i can really only do pretty basic stuff. flexbox is a possibility, but doesn't seem to size them properly.

Also I believe this is SP 2016, so. Sorry for that.

Help?!
THANK YOU!